# Discord js giveaway command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am currently trying to make a Discord.js command where the first person who reacts wins the prize. There are 2 issues that I am encountering right now. First, the bot is picking up the last prize that was entered through with the command rather than the current one. Secondly, the giveaway sent before a bot restart won't work after the bot restarts.

Here is the code:

```
const DropModel = require('../modules/DropModel');
const { MessageEmbed, ReactionCollector } = require("discord.js")
const { COLOR, MONGO } = require("../util/BotUtil");

module.exports = {
    name: "drop",
    description: "First to react wins the giveaway!",
    async execute(message, args) {
        
        let prizes = args.slice(0).join(' ').toString()

        if (!prizes) return message.channel.send("You didn't provide a prize.");

        const newDrop = new DropModel({
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            prize: prizes,
            channelId: message.channel.id,
            createdBy: message.author,
            timeCreated: new Date(),
        });

        newDrop.save();

        let Drops = await DropModel.findOne({ guildId: message.guild.id, channelId: message.channel.id });

        if (!Drops) return;

        const { prize, createdBy } = Drops;

        const DropEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${prize}`)
        .setDescription(`First to React with  wins the giveaway
        Hosted by: ${createdBy}`)
        .setColor(COLOR)
        .setTimestamp();

        const dropMsg = await message.channel.send(` **giveaway** `, DropEmbed);

        await Drops.remove();

        await dropMsg.react('');

        const filter = (reaction, user) => !user.bot;
        const reaction = new ReactionCollector(dropMsg, filter, { max: 1 });

        reaction.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
            const { embeds } = dropMsg;

            const embed = embeds[0];

            embed.setTitle(`Someone called giveaway!`);
            embed.setDescription(`Winner: ${user.toString()}    
            Please contact ${createdBy} to claim your giveaway!`);
            
            await dropMsg.edit(embed);

            dropMsg.channel.send(`${user.toString()} won **${prize}**!`);
        });
    }
}
```

Any help regarding the issues mentioned above would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd issue is normal. You would want to host your bot, Otherwise any information will be lost as soon as your bot shuts off

Comment: As Elitezen mentioned, the 2nd issue is expected. If you want to solve that 2nd issue, you'll need to save the data for the giveaway in a database or JSON file whenever a giveaway is created, and when the bot starts up (in your `client.on("ready")` handler) you should check the database/file to see if any giveaways are currently running. If any giveaways are supposed to be running (meaning they are still saved in the database/file), you would need to recreate the reaction collectors for each one. And once a giveaway ends, you would need to remove it from the database/file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the giveaway end timestamp in JSON file or whatever database and then delete it when it's finished.